# How to Apply RowStyle

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid on which I want to have a custom RowStyle.  I've created this style:

```
<Style
    TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
    x:Key="styRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and point to it as:

```
RowStyle="{StaticResource styRow}"
```

Yet the Style is not being applied to the selected row.  Why?

Comment: It's because in the Template of the Row, which you have not edited, there is a Trigger that changes the Background.

Comment: Mishka, I don't think the DataGrid has a RowTemplate.

Comment: I meant in the row's Style, there is a setter for Template.
And in its value, a ControlTemplate, there is a trigger that changes its Background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row style is actually being applied but the cell style is overriding it. So you could make the background color for the cell style either transparent or the same as the row style. Try this:

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="array1" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>String 2</sys:String>
            <sys:String>String 3</sys:String>
        </x:Array>

        <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
            x:Key="styRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"
            x:Key="styCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource array1}" 
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource styRow}"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource styCell}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT 1:** Please notice it is NOT ***my approach***, like you commented. The cell style is applied anyway. I'm just making it explicit so you can understand what is happening. In your post, you thought the row style was not being applied... and I'm showing you it actually is. If you remove `x:Key="styCell"` from the style definition and then remove it from the data grid cell style, it will still be applied as the default style. So, again: not my "approach", just making it clear. It does solve the problem though, if you modify the cell style background like mentioned before.

**EDIT 2:** Slightly modified XAML that explicitly applies only the row style. The default cell style modified to transparent.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>

        <x:Array x:Key="array1" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>String 2</sys:String>
            <sys:String>String 3</sys:String>
        </x:Array>

        <Style x:Key="styRow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>


    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource array1}" 
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource styRow}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Binding="{Binding}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 2" Binding="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT 3:** This is the **default cell style** that is applied if you do nothing. Note the `IsSelected` property trigger sets `Background` to `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey`:

[image]

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: @SezMe : did it help ?

Comment: I think so but I'm still working on the problem.  In your approach, it appears to me that styRow has no use.  Right?

Comment: It does have a use when you're applying the style to an entire row and not cell by cell.

Comment: Please see **EDIT 1, EDIT 2** and **EDIT 3**.

Comment: Thanks for a very complete and instructive reply.

Comment: @SezMe : You're very welcome ! Please remember to [VOTE UP](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer that was helpful to you. Thanks !

Comment: If I mark your reply as the answer (which I did) don't you get the points for that?  Are there additional bennies for an upvote?